# Number of Likes is not increasing in the template but it's works in admin

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I follow a tutorial in youtube just to add a like button to my Blog application, but the number of likes is not increasing in the template. but its increase when I highlight a user and hit save in the admin area. I mean its working fine in the admin but not in template.

How can I set that ?

the model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_posts')

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.category)
```

the view:

```
def like(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=request.GET.get('post_id'))
    post.Likes.add(request.user)   

    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('view', args=[str(pk)]))

def viewPhoto(request, pk):

    post = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)

    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=pk)

    stuff = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)

    total_likes = stuff.total_likes()

    return render(request, 'photo.html', {'photo': photo, 'post': post, 'total_likes': 
    total_likes})
```

the templates:

```
     <form action="{% url 'Photo' photo.id %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ total_likes }}
      <button type="submit", name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}">Touch</button>

 </form>
```

the urls:

```
path('', views.login, name='login'),
path('home', views.home, name='home'),
path('view/<str:pk>/', views.viewPhoto, name='Photo'),
path('post/create', views.PostCreativeView.as_view(), name='post_create'),
path('register', views.register, name='register'),
path('comment/<str:pk>/', views.comment, name='comment'),
path('like/<str:pk>/', views.like, name='like_post'),
```

Comment: I feel like form action should be `{% url 'like_post' photo.id %}`

Comment: But it's doesn't work, it's doesn't count the number of likes sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's very simple to get the number of liked objects in your form by simple doing something like this :

```
# In your view add s to the post variable 
def viewPhoto(request, pk):

    posts = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)

    photo = Photo.objects.get(id=pk)

    stuff = get_object_or_404(Photo, id=pk)

    total_likes = stuff.total_likes()

    return render(request, 'photo.html', {'photo': photo, 'posts': posts, 'total_likes': 
    total_likes})


{% for post in posts %}
<form action="{% url 'like_post' photo.id %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ post.likes.count }} # this would count and give you the total number of likes
       
      <button type="submit", name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}">Touch</button>

 </form>
{% endfor %}
# OR
{% for post in posts %}
  <form action="{% url 'like_post' photo.id %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ total_likes }} # this would count and give you the total number of likes
      <button type="submit", name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}">Touch</button>

 </form>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Either way would work with counting the number of liked objects!

Comment: Thank you, but how can I count the number of likes please ?

Comment: It's doesn't count the number of likes sir, what variable should I define to count my Likes

Comment: You need to loop through the photo object and then you use the post.likes.count to count every object that is liked . i will illustrate that in the my answer.

Comment: I just updated my answered have a look and used it !